# How can I call an anonymous function (stored in string) with an argument in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation in JavaScript:

```
<a onclick="handleClick(this, {onSuccess : 'function() { alert(\'test\') }'});">Click</a>
```

The `handleClick` function receives the second argument as a object with a `onSuccess` property containing the function definition...

**How do I call the `onSuccess` function (which is stored as string) -and- pass `otherObject` to that function? (jQuery solution also fine...)?**

This is what I've tried so far...

```
function handleClick(element, options, otherObject) {
    options.onSuccess = 'function() {alert(\'test\')}';

    options.onSuccess(otherObject); //DOES NOT WORK
    eval(options.onSuccess)(otherObject); //DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really don't need to do this. Pass the function around as a string, i mean. JavaScript functions are first-class objects, and can be passed around directly:

```
<a onclick="handleClick(this, {onSuccess : function(obj) { alert(obj) }}, 'test');">
  Click
</a>
```

...

```
function handleClick(element, options, otherObject) {
    options.onSuccess(otherObject); // works...
}
```

But if you *really* want to do it your way, then [cloudhead's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984138/javascript-execute-anonymous-function-stored-in-string-with-argument/984171#984171) will do just fine.

Comment: bah... and here I was in the middle of writing my exposition on the scope of eval. +1 for answering the real question.

Comment: Yeah I ended up doing this, but this means I can't use the json_encode in PHP anymore... this encapsulates everything in strings..

Comment: @ropstah: not sure why you're trying to pass function definitions down via JSON... Unless you're actually generating these functions on the fly, server-side, you may want to consider putting together a library of functions and then just *naming* them in the JSON. You can then look up the function you want without bothering with eval()

Comment: Great comment, I will actually do this

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 options.onSuccess = eval('function() {alert(\'test\')}');
 options.onSuccess(otherObject);
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as: eval('function() {alert(\'test\')}')(otherObject);

Comment: As Itay notes, you'll want to parenthesize the parameter to eval('(' + options.onSuccess + ')') - otherwise, FF will choke. Sorry, forgot about that...

Answer (score 0):

It only worked on my FF when I added an assignmnet into a dummy variable:

```
 options.onSuccess = 'dummyVariable = function(x) {alert("x=" + x);}';
 f = eval(options.onSuccess);
 f(5);
```

Comment: Heh, good catch. But rather than introducing dummyVariable, you can just wrap the value in parentheses.